# "Error: write after end" with csv-write-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am sure this is a fundamentally misunderstanding of how streams work, but I am banging my head on the wall.

I have some sensor data in json format that I want to append to a csv file using the csv-write-stream package.  The data is sent as a post request to a node server with the intention of having it appended to a csv file. It writes a line to the csv file fine the first time, but then I get "Error: write after end" error if I try to send another post request.

```
function write_csv(obj) {
    writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('tides.csv', { flags: 'a' }));
    writer.write(obj);
    writer.end();
};
```

If I comment out "writer.end()" it works fine, but won't this eventually throw a memory error?  If so, what is the correct way to append to a csv file and avoid this error?

EDIT:  Here is the entire server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const fs = require('fs');
const csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');

const writer = csvWriter({ sendHeaders: false });
const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home')
})

app.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    // console.log("post received");
    distance = req.body.distance;
    let result = test(distance);
    let result_str = JSON.stringify(result);
    res.end(result_str)
});

function write_csv(obj) {
    writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv', { flags: 'a' }));
    writer.write(obj);
    writer.end();
};

function test(dist) {
    let d = new Date();
    let YYYY = d.getFullYear();
    let MM = d.getMonth();
    let DD = d.getDate();
    let HH = d.getHours();
    let mm = d.getMinutes();
    let ss = d.getSeconds();
    let date = YYYY + ':' + (MM + 1) + ':' + DD + ':' + HH + ':' + mm + ':' + ss;
    let time_distance = { 'time': date, 'distance': distance };
    console.log(time_distance);
    write_csv(time_distance);
    return time_distance;
};


app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Sever started on port ' + app.get('port'));
})
```

Comment: `writer.write(obj);` doesn't wait for the write to finish before returning ... so `write.end()` is executed immediately, rather than once the write finishes

Comment: try `function write_csv(obj) {
    writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('tides.csv', { flags: 'a' }));
    writer.write(obj, () =>writer.end());
};`

Comment: @JaromandaX that's not really the problem, because `.write` will no write to disk every time it is called, it will only do it when `highWaterMark` threshold is reached, or when `.end` is called. so `writer.write(); writer.end();` is fine.

Comment: Oh, ok, so the problem doesn't exist :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the full code, I can imagine that you're calling `write_csv` multiple times, since you're trying to write multiple objects to that file.

The issue is that the first time you call `write_csv` you're ending the `writer`, that's why the second time you call it you get:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
```

---

```
function write_csv(obj) {
    writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv', { flags: 'a' }))
    writer.write()
    writer.end();
}
write_csv({ hello: 'world', foo: 'bar', baz: 'taco'});
// When you call it again, writer.end(); is already closed
// The following line will trigger the error
write_csv({ hello: 'world', foo: 'bar', baz: 'taco'});
```

What you should do instead, is close the writer only when you're done writing to it.

```
const writer = csvWriter(); // Create new writer
// open file
writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv', { flags: 'a' }));

for(const obj of objects) // Write as many times as you wish
   writer.write(obj);

writer.end(); // I'm done writing.
```

---

Now the problem you have, is that if you try to perform multiple `.writes` you will reach memory limit, because you're not dealing with [backpressure](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/) correctly.

I recommend reading the following question:

[why does attempting to write large a large file cause js heap to run out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357777/why-does-attempting-to-write-large-a-large-file-cause-js-heap-to-run-out-of-memo/50360972#50360972)

To deal with that, you will need to wait for the `drain` event to be emitted.

Here is a wrapper around `csvWriter` that will handle backpressure.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');

class Writer {

    constructor(file) {
        this.writer = csvWriter();
        this.writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file, { flags: 'a' }));
    }

    write(obj) {
        // if .write returns false we have to wait until `drain` is emitted
        if(!this.writer.write(obj))
            return new Promise(resolve => this.writer.once('drain', resolve))

        return true;
    }

    end() {
        // Wrap it in a promise if you wish to wait for the callback.
        this.writer.end(); 
    }

}

(async() => {
    const writer = new Writer('out.csv');

    for(let i = 0; i < 1e8; i++) {
        const res = writer.write({ hello: 'world', foo: 'bar', baz: 'taco' });
        if(res instanceof Promise) {
            // You can remove this if, and leave just: await writer.write...
            // but the code will be slower
            await res; // This will wait for the stream to emit the drain event
        }
    }

    writer.end();

})();
```

---

**Update**: Now with the actual code, the above answer still stands, but since you're writing to the file when receiving a request. You can choose whether to open the file once, and write on every request, close it when the server shuts down (or when you choose). or just open the file, write to it, and close it on every request,

For the former, you should use the answer above, for the latter, all you need to do, is create a new writer every time you call `write_csv` instead of having one global writer.

```
function write_csv(obj) {
    // Create a new writer every time
    const writer = csvWriter({ sendHeaders: false }); 
    writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv', { flags: 'a' }));
    writer.write(obj);
    writer.end();
};
```

Comment: Thanks marcos. I edited the original post to include the entire code.  I am still trying to wrap my head around promises/async stuff with node, but i'm afraid I haven't quite hit the 'a-ha moment'.  This is supposed to be a simple project to take distance measurements from my dock using a nodemcu / ultrasonic sensor and upload them to a raspberry pi in my house to create a tide table.  I figured that this would be pretty straight forward as far as logging that data to a csv file (its not).  My limited background is mainly python, so embracing this asynchronous stuff has been a challenge.

Comment: Check my updated answer, since I have seen your code now. And let me know if there's anything that is not clear in my answer.

Comment: That did the trick, works like a champ.  Like you said, I needed to create a new writer within the function, not at the beginning of the server.js script.  I imagine that little lesson will come up again in the future with any WriteStream functions.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code instead, I thinks it solves your problem. Use this function in your route and pass the json data.

First install this package: `npm i --save json2csv`

```js
const Json2csvParser = require("json2csv").Parser;
const fs = require("fs");

function csvConverter(jsonData, cb) {

  const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser();
  const csv_data = json2csvParser.parse(jsonData);
  const file_name = "report";

  // TODO: Change file path accordingly
  const file_path = `/Users/public/csv_files/${file_name}.csv`;

  fs.appendFile(file_path, csv_data, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      cb(err, null);
      return;
    }
    const response = {
    msg: "successful",
    file_address: file_path
  };
    cb(null, response);
    return;
  });
}
```